# Code to Match Value of Colum 1 against Column 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small userform with one combobox, textbox and command button whose image is attached.[image]

There is one table on sheet 1 whose image is attached below.
[image]

What I want is when I press the command button in the userform, it has to check each time a value in column 1 against value in column 2.

For example,
if column 1 has value "Non Current Assets" and against it column 2 has value "PPE", then msgbox will appear "Value Exist".

The code has to check each time the value1 of column1 against value1 of column2
and if its not there then msgbox will appear "Value not Exist".

Here is my code:

> Blockquote

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Declaring the Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, row As ListRow
Dim value1 As String, value2 As String
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

ws.Unprotect Password:="google"

Set rng1 = tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
Set rng2 = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange

value1 = LCase(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
value2 = LCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)

'Loop to Check for the Group Head Existence
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
For Each rng1 In rng1
    If LCase(rng1.Value) = value1 Then
        For Each rng2 In rng2
            If LCase(rng2.Value) = value2 Then
            MsgBox ("Value Exist.")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox ("Value not Exist")
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
            End If
    Next rng2
End If
Next rng1
End If
End Sub
```

The code is not checking the value1 of column1 against value1 in column2.

Kindly advise.

Comment: "The code is not checking the value1 of column1 against value1 in column2." What it is doing then?

Comment: It is only reading the values in column 2 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code within If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then  statement

```
For Each cell In rng1
        If LCase(cell.Value) = value1 and LCase(cell.offset(0,1).Value)=value2 Then
                MsgBox ("Value Exist.")
                Exit Sub
        Else
                MsgBox ("Value not Exist")
                Unload Me
                Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thevar, it is only checking for 1st row. However it is not checking the other values.

Comment: You can just remove the code in else statement and use the following code after for statemet MsgBox ("Value not Exist")
                Unload Me
                Exit Sub

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do

```
For Each rng1 In rng1
```

instead, you have to loop throw cells in rng1, like

```
dim cel as range

for each cel in rng1
```

Same thing for

```
For Each rng2 In rng2
```

Try to modify and see what it will give you